# Using ASync Task to display data in LIstView on postExecute

Tags: android

the problem that im having is kind of weird the printstack of the JSON is correct displaying all the element in the table the way that it should the same as for the method String doInBackground(String... args) the problem is in the postExecute method that is displaying the same element in all the element of the listview "the last element in the row of the table to be exact can someone tell me what i did wrong " thank you for your time bellow you will find the class that im talking about thank you

```
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProDentActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Balance. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(balanceURL, "GET", params);
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    amount = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BALANCE);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < amount.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = amount.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String amount = c.getString(TAG_AMOUNT);
                        String createdat = c.getString(TAG_CREATEDAT);
                        //String userid = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_AMOUNT, amount);
                        map.put(TAG_CREATEDAT, createdat);
                        //map.put(TAG_USERID , userid);
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        amountlist.add(map);


                    }
                } else {
                    // no balance found
                    // Launch Add New balance Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ProDentActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            ProDentActivity.this, amountlist,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_AMOUNT,TAG_CREATEDAT},
                            new int[] { R.id.amount, R.id.createdat });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);


                }
            });

        }

    }
```

JSON:

```
{"balance":[{"amount":"50000","created_at":"2012-12-15 02:39:13"},{"amount":"50000","created_at":"2012-12-16 15:29:03"},{"amount":"30000","created_at":"2012-12-17 19:38:07"}],"success":1}
```

...and the method returns

```
12-18 02:29:05.797: D/All Products:(885): {"success":1,"balance":[{"amount":"50000","created_at":"2012-12-15 02:39:13"},{"amount":"50000","created_at":"2012-12-16 15:29:03"},{"amount":"30000","created_at":"2012-12-17 19:38:07"}]}
```

Comment: You don't have to use `runOnUiThread()`
 in `onPostExecute`. It already has access to the UI thread.

Comment: what should i use in order to make it work

Comment: Remove the runOnUiThread

Comment: same problem any other suggestions ?

Comment: What does your LogCat print?

Comment: the JSON:12-18 02:29:05.677: E/JSON(885): {"balance":[{"amount":"50000","created_at":"2012-12-15 02:39:13"},{"amount":"50000","created_at":"2012-12-16 15:29:03"},{"amount":"30000","created_at":"2012-12-17 19:38:07"}],"success":1} and the method returns
12-18 02:29:05.797: D/All Products:(885): {"success":1,"balance":[{"amount":"50000","created_at":"2012-12-15 02:39:13"},{"amount":"50000","created_at":"2012-12-16 15:29:03"},{"amount":"30000","created_at":"2012-12-17 19:38:07"}]}

Comment: For Eclipse: go to Window -> Show View -> Android -> LogCat.

Comment: what do you think the data received is valid and correct the problem is with the display in the list view

Comment: thank you for your time if anything came up to your mind regarding this issue please keep me updated

Comment: @Ahmad there are two json strings and they are both valid

Comment: @rds oh, hahah didn't see that. @ Joe so the json is not invalid, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed i found what i have been doing wrong. the problem was that i didn't define my hash map in the method  protected String doInBackground(String... args)

i was defining it in the listactivity anw thank you for your time and help
bellow code to be replaced with the old one
          try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

```
            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                amount = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BALANCE);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < amount.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = amount.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String amount = c.getString(TAG_AMOUNT);
                    String createdat = c.getString(TAG_CREATEDAT);
                    //String userid = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_AMOUNT, amount);
                    map.put(TAG_CREATEDAT, createdat);
                    //map.put(TAG_USERID , userid);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    amountlist.add(map);


                }
            } else {
                // no balance found
                // Launch Add New balance Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ProDentActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```